# Is it possible to have single checkbox for multiple values to the below design?

Tags: css, checkbox, checkboxlist

[image]

I have tried searching in the internet but couldn't find appropriate solution to this, Can anyone help me out

Comment: What have you searched on Google (or any other search engine)? Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: Please give the details in the description. Not as title of question

Comment: I am not able to find the design code however i found solution for 'one checkbox to check or uncheck many other checkboxes at once' , which i already knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay...so you want the CSS only...Please check the following code and adjust according to your size and need

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<input style="float:left;" type="checkbox" />
<label class="form-check-label"><br>First line <br> Second line <br> third line</label>
```

Comment: perfect! thank you so much it worked

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is possible. However you can use one checkbox to check or uncheck many other checkboxes at once. You can use the below code to do that

```js
$('#selectAllBoxes').click(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {

    $('.checkBoxes').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    $('.checkBoxes').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="selectAllBoxes" id="selectAllBoxes">
```

Comment: i knew this function, i just need the css for the above design. btw thanks for your solution.